# how to hide "API URL" and "API KEY" from "ApiResources.java"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-developer-api

**my ApiResources.java look like this**

```
package com.example.utils;

import com.example.R;

public class ApiResources {

    public static String adStatus="0",adMobBannerId="null", adMobInterstitialId="null", adMobPublisherId="null";


    String URL = "http://example/api/";

    String API_SECRECT_KEY = "api_secret_key=1kkzczxc8fny1fagc";
```

Comment: _[What's the difference between JavaScript and Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)_

Answer (score 3):

### Step 1: Defining your key outside source code

Place the below line in your user-level `gradle.properties` file.

```
MyAwesomeApp_ApiKey="your-api-key-goes-here"
```

I prefer to use this format `<Project Name>_<Key Property Name>` so that I don’t mix up keys for different projects by mistake.

### Step 2: Importing the key in your project

- Open your module-level `build.gradle` file (usually the one where you define dependencies for your app).
- Add your property in each of your build types.
- If you want to access the key from Java, then add it as a `buildConfigField`.
- If you want to access the key in your XML files (layouts and other resources), then add it as a `resValue`.

After doing that your `build.gradle` might look like this

```
buildTypes {
  debug {
    buildConfigField 'String', "ApiKey", MyAwesomeApp_ApiKey
    resValue 'string', "api_key", MyAwesomeApp_ApiKey
  }
  release {
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    buildConfigField 'String', "ApiKey", MyAwesomeApp_ApiKey
    resValue 'string', "api_key", MyAwesomeApp_ApiKey
  }
}
```

### Step 3: Using the key in your app's code

- In Java now you can simply replace all your uses of `API_SECRET_KEY` with `BuildConfig.ApiKey`.
- In XML, you can refer to the key using `@string/api_key`.